# @EnableWebMvc annotation is affecting some mapping in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, mapping

When i add @EnableWebMvc annotation in my project it doesnt map webjars and favicon.

I am getting this warning when I load index page which call webjars inside:

```
    No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
    No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/webjars/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
    No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/favicon.ico] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

it is working without problems when i remove this anotation, what is the reason of this? how can i solve this problem?

I  also need this annotation for only handling 'NoHandlerFoundException' like this :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {


    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public ModelAndView handlerNoHandlerFoundException() {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("errorpage");
        modelAndView.addObject("errorTitle", "404 Not Found ");
        modelAndView.addObject("errorDescription", "The page you are looking for is not available now!!! ");
        System.out.println("ERROR :::::::::::::::::::::: no handler");
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

what do you recommend for this situation?

Comment: if it's working without problems when you remove the annotation, what's your problem? Just don't have the annotation.

Comment: @eis I also need this annotation for exception handling

Comment: please add the exception handling details you need to the question, then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Per the Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-switch-off-default-mvc-configuration), using `@EnableWebMvc` disables MVC autoconfiguration and allows you to provide exactly what you want. In this case, that means that it switches off the default resource and WebJar mappings.

You can either use other means to customize your configuration, such as a `*Configurer`, or you can specify exactly what you want with `@EnableWebMvc`. See Boot's `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` to find out what the defaults are, and copy over the pieces that you need.